# Performance testing in Go - Where to start from?

Tags: performance, testing, time, go, automated-tests

I've been learning Go. I'm just a newbie. I've just finished my web (still in localhost). I want to ask if there is any tools or framework, library that allows to test server performance, track response time parallel to running server.

I don't know where to begin from, criteria is from measuring response time for each request, creating virtual automatic session to send request to server (login, do something, logout), calculating how many requests sent simultaneously to server are properly responded, etc.

What should I start now? And what will I use?

Comment: Which server you're using Apache, nginx or other?

Comment: Jmeter, wrk, siege -  try those.

Comment: @GauravDave I'm using nginx

Comment: Gatling is good. But start with reading and build an understanding what types of performance measurements you want, need and can do.

Answer (score 2):

Using the built in tools should be most of what you need, you just need to learn about the tooling, like writing Benchmark test functions.

[This go blog post](http://blog.golang.org/profiling-go-programs) has an overview and links to info about the cpu/memory/contention tooling.

Brad Fitzpatrick gave [a good talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xxDZuPEgbBU) about using the profiling tools, with examples.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to test the code you write in go you should build `benchmark` test. To achieve this result read the golang documentation about the package `testing` [here](https://golang.org/pkg/testing/). If you have any question feel free to write here

Comment: Because I'm testing a web application that includes logging in, doing stuffs, handling requests, managing session, and logging out, I wonder if `testing` could help me test? It concerns with user session, so I'm worried about it

Comment: The package `testing` is massive used for unit test, if you are interested benchmark how much time your function take for loggin - loggin out etc there is not a problem, for the session you can esy create a fake session and use it for testing. You can check [this](http://dave.cheney.net/2013/06/30/how-to-write-benchmarks-in-go) usefull post.

Comment: How can I create a fake session. Each session is created by logging in with Google OAuth

Comment: You can invoke the api in the test function

Comment: I've still been learning. Where is it? Can you guide me? Thank you

Comment: You can invoke the session creation in the function of the benchmark you will create after thath you can make all the test you want. Check also [this link](https://www.golang-book.com/books/intro/12) to understand how you should make test (benchmark is a "child" of test)

Answer (score 1):

1. Take a load testing tool, [here](http://www.opensourcetesting.org/performance.php) is the list of 54 (as for now) free and open source load testing tools. If you want something short-listed check out [Open Source Load Testing Tools: Which One Should You Use?](https://blazemeter.com/blog/open-source-load-testing-tools-which-one-should-you-use) article
2. It's better to have another host to run your load test from to avoid mutual interference.
3. Run load test (most tools have record and replay functionality, it should be enough for baseline testing)
4. If you're unhappy with response times or get errors - investigate and fix the reason which could be:

   - lack of resources (CPU, RAM, Network or Disk IO) on your web application side
   - not optimal configuration of application or web server
   - something is wrong with your application code

Comment: I've been struggling with getting certificate in Gatling. Could you help me please?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36545399/error-self-signed-certificate-getting-chain